# How can I access a JS-exported module object from Java using GraalVM?

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm

I have some JS code that looks roughly like this:

```js
let ssr = async (arg) => arg || "hello js";
export {ssr as default};
```

I want to access and call `ssr` from Java.

How can I do that?

I've been trying something like this:

```java
var ctx = Context.newBuilder("js")
                .allowIO(true)
                .allowHostAccess(HostAccess.ALL)
                .build();

        var ssrResource = new String(Server.class.getResourceAsStream("/ssr.mjs").readAllBytes());

        ctx.eval(Source
                .newBuilder("js", ssrResource, "ssr.mjs")
                .build());
        var ssr = ctx.getBindings("js").getMember("ssr");
```

But this always returns null.

Comment: Very good question. I am also searching for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values exported from a module can be imported by another module using the `import` syntax. For example, you could have another file loading your module, like:

```
// -- some-module-file.mjs
import ssr from 'ssr.mjs'
ssr;
```

and then execute the file via:

```
File file = loadSomehow("some-module-file.mjs");
Source mainSource = Source.newBuilder("js", file).mimeType("application/javascript+module").build();
Value ssr = context.eval(mainSource);
```

Here, `Value ssr` is the value exported by your module with `export {ssr as default};`

Comment: That seems helpful. I will try it and accept the answer if it works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following java code

```
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var ctx = Context.newBuilder("js").allowAllAccess(true).build();
        ctx.eval("js", "let ssr = async (arg) => arg || \"hello js\"");
        var v = ctx.getBindings("js").getMember("ssr");
        System.out.println(v.execute());
    }
}
```

outputs

```
Promise{[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: "hello js"}
```

On GraalVM CE 20.0.0 so I assume there is something wrong with the way you build your `Source` object.

Comment: It doesn't work if you use the script as I posted, with an exports clause.

Comment: notice that this is a JS module I am trying to use (hence the file extension, `mjs`) I can't change the JS code.

Comment: maybe you could import the module and assign `ssr` from it to something global to pass it to the bindings?

Comment: @Renato Ah, quite! Missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into testExportNamespace function at https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/blob/master/graal-js/src/com.oracle.truffle.js.test/src/com/oracle/truffle/js/test/interop/ESModuleTest.java

Hint is to use

1. allowExperimentalOptions(true) in Context builder
2. option(JSContextOptions.ESM_EVAL_RETURNS_EXPORTS_NAME, "true"); in Context builder
3. Set .mimeType(JavaScriptLanguage.MODULE_MIME_TYPE) in Source builder

Regards
Saurabh